# Navbar elements made up of bootstrap , active state not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I Made a Navbar using Bootstrap Code... But even after mentioning 'active' state in li class of my navbar , it is not showing any 'active' effect on web page on Navbar elements.

Actually I was trying to Add and Remove Active class on Navbar Elements..But i cannot solve above problem first...Can You Please Help me...?

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.85;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.9s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-menu a:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
}

.nav-menu a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #C72C41;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-width" role="navigation"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm nav-menu" id="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">\harsh_sharma/</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarid">
    
                    <span id="tc"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#header">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently struggling with a similar problem. The issue is, some more recent versions of bootstrap do not support the active class for elements within the base .nav class. This can be found here.[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#base-nav]
The solution is to describe the active class yourself in the stylesheet. the active class is then placed on the link. So that the link has a class of "nav-link active"
If after defining your .active class in the stylesheet, you place directly on the list, the nav-link styling would override yours due to specificity. This can be read about here. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity]. I have edited your code and the home element is now active. Thank you!

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.85;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.9s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-menu a:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
}

.nav-menu a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #C72C41;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
.active {
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-width" role="navigation"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm nav-menu" id="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">\harsh_sharma/</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarid">
    
                    <span id="tc"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#header">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```